# Call base constructor with method as argument

Tags: c#, .net

I am a beginner in C# and cannot find out how to call a base constructor from within a subclass:

Base class:

```
public class LookupScript
{
    protected Func<IEnumerable> getItems;

    protected LookupScript()
    {
        //
    }

    public LookupScript(Func<IEnumerable> getItems) : this()
    {
        Check.NotNull(getItems, "getItems");
        this.getItems = getItems;
    }
```

My derived class:

```
public class PresenceLookup : LookupScript
{
    public PresenceLookup() :base(??)
    {
     //
    }
    List<string> myMethod()
    {
        return null;
    }
```

How can I pass `myMethod` to the base class?

Thank you

Comment: As an aside, it's worth presenting a [mcve] in questions - here, `lookupParams` hasn't been declared and appears to be irrelevant, ditto `Check.NotNull`, and the parameterless constructor is irrelevant. A complete class that just consists of the parameterized constructor would be better.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, as `myMethod` is an instance method, and you can't access anything to do with the instance being created within the constructor initializer. This would work though:

```
public class PresenceLookup : LookupScript
{
    public PresenceLookup() : base(MyMethod)
    {
    }

    private static List<string> MyMethod()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

That uses a *method group conversion* to create a `Func<List<string>>` that will call `MyMethod`.

Or if you don't need the method for anything else, just use a lambda expression:

```
public class PresenceLookup : LookupScript
{
    public PresenceLookup() : base(() => null)
    {
    }
}
```